# Can't open Tor Browser with Greek IP

Tags: ip-address

There is something weird going on. I wanted to enter Tor Browser using a greek IP but can't connect. I think i'm doing everything correct since I am able to connect using US IP, German IP, even New Zealand and Iceland IPs.

I am changing ExitNodes {Country} and saving notepad. It works with other countries as I told you but can't work with ExitNodes {GR}

I need specific greek IP for geotagging reason in webTV

Is there anything I can do? All other countries are working... :O

Comment: Run an exit in Greece.

Comment: Pay for a VPN in Greece.

Comment: Buy a server in Greece.

Comment: Ask someone in Greece to provide you with connectivity.

Comment: what you mean ask someone to provide me with connectivity? Isn't a free way to change my IP to greek IP? I have done it to dozen other countries as i explained this way. Why Greece is a special case? Am I doing something wrong? :/

Comment: Still no exit nodes in Greece.

Comment: Other have already stated this. Please be more specific and detailed in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

> All other countries are working...

According to https://compass.torproject.org, there are no exit relays in Greece, so you can't get a Greek IP through Tor.

> Is there anything I can do?

Like canonizing ironize said, you can run an exit node in Greece, get a VPN in Greece, or ask someone else to set one up for you in Greece.

Answer (score 0):

It means there are no exit nodes in Greece right now or you need to make sure you have `StrictNodes 1` turned on in conjunction with the country setting or there are ExitNodes in Greece but they are not reporting as such (ExitNodes {??}).

So make sure your torrc has `StrictNodes 1` and `ExitNodes {gr}` and report back if that works. Case might also matter. Haven't checked if it does or not, so GR vs gr.

Comment: https://onionoo.torproject.org/details?country=GR there are no exits in Greece (according to GeoIP which isn't accurate anyway) and the country codes are case insensitive.