# Where can I find a specific node to exit from?

Tags: node

I have been doing a bit of research and I know it is as simple as adding the 
"Exitnodes IP address" command to the torrc file. I was just wondering if there is a publicly available list of IP addresses so that I may be able to find a better bandwidth. I am just trying to access a website to make it think I am an Argentinian user, but when I do the Exitnodes {ar} configuration, Tor connects but every website times out.

Comment: There appears to be only one exit in Argentina.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't open Tor Browser with Greek IP](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/12321/cant-open-tor-browser-with-greek-ip)

Comment: If you're doing it for better bandwidth, this won't help you. The bandwidth of the tor connection is minimum of bandwidth between you and entry node,  nodes themselves, between exit note and destination as well as any limits any of the node imposes. Just specifying exit node will not give you anything, even if it has very fast connection between itself and the destination server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to elaborate a TorStatus script - like [here](https://torstatus.blutmagie.de/index.php#CustomQuery) and filter by country. However - just a side note - check your connection, because even from out far - but to make *every* site to time out - well, that's odd... I've never met THIS kind of situation just by itself, usually it was a bad connectivity to Tor network, i.e. ISP connection and modem/router problems. Check this part. If you'll add some details about your router/modem and connection type - I'll be able to help you further